# which field is tcp tcp_offset field in tcphdr in netinet/tcp.h file is it th_offset or doff

Tags: c, linux, tcp

so this is the macro and code to extract payload of a tcp packet

```
static void display(struct tpacket3_hdr *ppd)
{
        struct ethhdr *eth = (struct ethhdr *) ((uint8_t *) ppd + ppd->tp_mac);
        struct iphdr *ip = (struct iphdr *) ((uint8_t *)eth + ETH_HLEN);
        struct tcphdr *tcp=(struct tcphdr *)((uint8_t *)ip+sizeof(struct iphdr));
        #define TCP_HLEN(tcp) ((tcp->tcp_offset & 0xf0) >> 2)

        char *payload_body=(char *)((uint8_t*)ppd+ppd->tp_mac+sizeof(struct iphdr) + TCP_HLEN(tcp)) ;
}
```

the define macro which will give `tcp_offset` since 4 bit tcp_offset (AND-ing) with 4 `1s` bit and moving output to the right to x in `0x0x` so this will be the tcp offset value and adding that to tcp thats the payload. But in tcphdr in `netinet/tcp.h` file it has `doff` and `th_off` one of them looks like tcp offset which one? whats the other one? or is there any other field I am missing to see. payload with  th_off were getting read some time ago on different linux destro but not I am using ubuntu but I dont think it matters.

tpacket3_hdr is just frame representation in ring buffer exposed by rx ring mapped buffer. for getting ethernet frame

this is tcphdr in netinet/tcp.h  file

```
struct tcphdr
  {
    __extension__ union
    {
      struct
      {
    uint16_t th_sport;  /* source port */
    uint16_t th_dport;  /* destination port */
    tcp_seq th_seq;     /* sequence number */
    tcp_seq th_ack;     /* acknowledgement number */
# if __BYTE_ORDER == __LITTLE_ENDIAN
    uint8_t th_x2:4;    /* (unused) */
    uint8_t th_off:4;   /* data offset */
# endif
# if __BYTE_ORDER == __BIG_ENDIAN
    uint8_t th_off:4;   /* data offset */
    uint8_t th_x2:4;    /* (unused) */
# endif
    uint8_t th_flags;
# define TH_FIN 0x01
# define TH_SYN 0x02
# define TH_RST 0x04
# define TH_PUSH    0x08
# define TH_ACK 0x10
# define TH_URG 0x20
    uint16_t th_win;    /* window */
    uint16_t th_sum;    /* checksum */
    uint16_t th_urp;    /* urgent pointer */
      };
```

Answer (score 0):

`tcphdr->th_off` is the correct one its tcp offset. sizeof tcphdr=th_off. But I figured it out by looking at the code that I was mapping RX right and not TX ring so I was not getting Get requests originating from my browser or curl/nc etc.

I wonder why linux/tcp.h contains `struct tcphdr` that has no `th_off` field. no tcp offset field. probably because no kernel code ever need to use tcp header this field which is higher level used in only userspace programs though realtek network driver uses file which I seen and but not uses tcp offset field